# How to specify a different context in SwiftUI then the main application viewContext?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, core-data, swiftui

I have an application which has multiple Core Data Models, one inside the main application and one inside a package.

The issue is that when calling Package Views from application which use FetchRequest to display data from its model I get an error.

> The fetch request's entity xxx 'Entity' appears to be from a different NSManagedObjectModel than this context

Specifying `NSPersistentContainer` **on each view** and then passing down to child view seems to work:

```
let packagePersistenceController = PackagePersistenceController.shared

SomeView()
  .environment(\.managedObjectContext, packagePersistenceController.container.viewContext)

struct SomeView() {

let packagePersistenceController = PackagePersistenceController.shared

  var body:some View {
     AnotherView()
       .environment(\.managedObjectContext, packagePersistenceController.container.viewContext)
  }
}
```

I wonder if there any other better option do accomplish this?

Comment: Generally the best way to go about this would be to do the whole `.environment(\.managedObjectContext, packagePersistenceController.container.viewContext)` thing on your app's root view. If you're using one or more `UIHostingController`(s), you'd set it on each controller's root view. If you still get errors, that implies something further down the hierarchy is changing the environment's managed object context for its child views

Answer (score 0):

Core Data is designed to work with one view context that uses multiple merged models and persistent stores all managed by a coordinator. When you fetch or insert you can choose which store to work with.

[`mergedModel(from:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectmodel/1506704-mergedmodel)
Returns a model created by merging all the models found in given bundles.

[`affectedStores`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchrequest/1506518-affectedstores)
An array of persistent stores specified for the fetch request.

[`assign(_:to:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext/1506436-assign)
Specifies the store in which a newly inserted object will be saved.